# React Bootstrap Navigation bar: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-bootstrap

It is showing this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render
>   method of `CustomNavbar`.

App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import home from './components/home';
import about from './components/about';
import menu from './components/menu';
import gallery from './components/gallery';
import franchise from './components/franchise';
import Navbar from './components/CustomNavbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path ="/" component={home} />
        <Route  path ="/about" component={about} />
        <Route  path ="/menu" component={menu} />
        <Route  path ="/gallery" component={gallery} />
        <Route  path ="/franchise" component={franchise} /> 
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

component.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class CustomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Link to="/">
              <img src="public/assets/i2.png" alt="thumbnail" />
            </Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle/>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} to="/">
              Home
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} to="/about">
              About
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} to="/menu">
              Menu
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={4} componentClass={Link} to="/gallery">
              Gallery
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={5} componentClass={Link} to="/franchise">
             Franchise
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `NavLink` is correct, or if it should be `Nav.Link`, the docs are a bit unclear on this (well, `NavLink` is in the code, but missing from docs). Other than that, I don't see `componentClass` listed anywhere as a valid prop. I think you want the `as` props to specify you really want a `Link`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Navbar.Header was removed from react-bootstrap in v1.0.0](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/7f17025dd27ac672e3b3aba0b3d6afbc336f186a/www/src/pages/migrating.mdx). To fix your issue, either downgrade your version of react-bootstrap (e.g. with `npm install react-bootstrap@0.32.0`) or change your code to not use `Navbar.Header`.